# Is there any way to join an update query and a delete query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-delete

I have an update query and a delete query. Is there any way to join these two queries like

```
update table_1 set id = '2' && delete table_2 where id = '3';
```

Comment: You can run them in the same transaction but they are two separate statements in all databases except for Postgres (which allows DML in CTEs).

Comment: I don't see any tags for what sql vendor/version you are using, but check out the MERGE statement for sql server if that applies.  Look at example B in particular: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx